# Weblogic cannot inject @PersistenceContext in static field

Tags: java, jpa, weblogic

I'm not very skilled on Weblogic, and maybe is a stupid question, but I'm unable to understand why the deploy fail if the persistence context will be injected in a static field.

```java
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "name")
private static EntityManager em;
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "em" in class "class_name" is defined as injection target with annotation @PersistenceContext, but "em" cannot be declared as static field.
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.injectiontarget.BaseValidator.error(BaseValidator.java:132)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.injectiontarget.BaseValidator.error(BaseValidator.java:149)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.injectiontarget.J2EEValidator.checkModifier(J2EEValidator.java:28)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AbstractAnnotationValidator.checkField(AbstractAnnotationValidator.java:57)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AbstractAnnotationValidator.validate(AbstractAnnotationValidator.java:26)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AnnotationValidatorVisitor.visitInjectionTargetBean(AnnotationValidatorVisitor.java:48)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.validator.AnnotationValidatorVisitor.visit(AnnotationValidatorVisitor.java:25)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1448)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.AbstractDescriptorBean.accept(AbstractDescriptorBean.java:1452)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.validate(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:205)
    at weblogic.j2ee.dd.xml.BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.validate(BaseJ2eeAnnotationProcessor.java:197)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.metadata.EjbAnnotationProcessor.processAnnotations(EjbAnnotationProcessor.java:260)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.metadata.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.processAnnotations(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:364)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBMetadataHandler.processAnnotations(EJBMetadataHandler.java:164)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBMetadataHandler.processAnnotations(EJBMetadataHandler.java:157)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.processAnnotations(EJBModule.java:175)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:370)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Comment: AFAIK static injection is not widely supported by JEE containers, since it has unclear semantics (e.g. how to handle classes that are shared across applications, which could theoretically happen for certain classloader configuration); also, an `EntityManager` needs to be closed at some point, making the static injection of `@PersistenceContext` particularly problematic

Comment: Also note that `EntityManager`s (unlike entity manager factories) are cheap-to-create, non-thread-safe, (usually) transaction-scoped objects, and so it virtually never makes sense to have a single global `EntityManager` bound to a static field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vincenzo and I are colleagues, so we would inform you that he solved the issue by configuring Weblogic in **production mode**.

The reason is still obscure, but for the moment it doesn't matter, because... it works!

Answer (score 0):

Should not `static` modifier, use non-static variable

Comment: Thanks, surely can be a solution, but I'm quite sure that is a misconfiguration problem, because I'm able to deploy it on another weblogic instance. Furthermore why is not possible to inject in a static field?

Comment: Because spring IoC container does not manage static resources